# How to test nested Fragments?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-fragments, robolectric

I have an app that works fine. However I decided to start implementing tests for it.
But now I run into some problems:

My App uses nested `Fragments` to use different stacks. I want to test a specific `Fragment` "FragmentInfo" that is nested in another `Fragment` "FragmentOuterInfo".
My test runs fine until I want to call the `ChildFragmentManager` of "FragmentOuterInfo". I get this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)...
```

I know there is a Framework called [robolectric](http://robolectric.org/), but first I want to know what the problem is and if it's possible to make tests with `ChildFragmentManager`. 
Perhaps someone knows a good way to test nested `Fragments`. 
I appreciate any hint.

My Code:

```
public class FragmentInfoTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    // KONSTANTE
    private static final String PKG = "com.example";
    private static final int MENU_INFO = com.example.R.id.info;

    // MEMBER
    private MainActivity mActivity;
    private FragmentInfo mFragInfo;


    // KONSTRUKTOR
    public FragmentInfoTest() {
        super(PKG, MainActivity.class); // calls Superclass with pkg & class under test
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception{
        super.setUp();
        // turn TouchMode off
        setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);

        // get MainActivity
        mActivity = getActivity();

        // click on MenuItem "INFO" 
            // -> I also see the FragmentInfo for a short time
        // so it has been init!
        getInstrumentation().invokeMenuActionSync(mActivity, MENU_INFO, 0);

    }

    public void testPreConditions(){
        // get outer Fragment
        FragmentOuterInfo infoOuter = mActivity.getFragmentOuterInfo();
        assertNotNull(infoOuter); // this check is fine


        // Here I get the error:
        FragmentManager manager = infoOuter.getChildFragmentManager();
        assertNotNull(manager);

    }
}
```

Additional Information:

- IDE: Android Studio 0.2.10
- I'm a newbie in unit tests :)

If you need the full Stacktrace -> tell me.
Thanks!

Comment: did you figured out the solution?